# iReport: How to format date based on French locale

Tags: localization, jasper-reports, ireport, date-formatting

I have a problem with formatting date in *iReport*

An my pc I configured the locale language as *French* but when the *iReport* generate the reports I find the date formated with *English* locale.

Here is a few code from my *jrxml* file :

```xml
<band height="41" splitType="Stretch">
    <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy h.mm a">
        <reportElement uuid="fb711e77-c949-4a99-9b52-109aae00c8ed" x="87" y="19" width="100" height="20"/>
        <textElement/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{datenow}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    <staticText>
        <reportElement uuid="51fb76a0-829e-4c36-b474-3ff9c7d4c239" x="41" y="19" width="48" height="20"/>
        <textElement>
            <font isBold="true" isItalic="true"/>
        </textElement>
        <text><![CDATA[Fes Le : ]]></text>
    </staticText>
</band>
```

and here is how it is displayed for me: *`Fri Sep 28 09:59:00`*

My target format is: *`vendredi 28 septembre 2012 09:59`* (in *French*)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can look at my answers on [How to change date format (month name) in iReport?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8654787/876298) and [Setting REPORT_LOCALE in IReport?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8847962/876298) posts related to your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question duplicates [How to change date format (month name) in iReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8653424/876298) and [Setting REPORT_LOCALE in IReport?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8847698/876298) posts.

---

- For setting locale in *iReport* you should call dialog *Options - Compilation and exectution* (via *iReport* -> *Tools* -> *Options* menu).

[image: Dialog for setting language]

For this *textField*:

```xml
<textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The result will be:

[image: Result via preview in iReport]

**Note**: It's works only for preview in *iReport*.

- For Java application you can set [**`JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE`**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JRParameter.html#REPORT_LOCALE) parameter.

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.FRENCH); 
JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(compiledReportName, params);
```

The result will be the same for report generated with code like this.

---

The working sample, *jrxml* file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...  whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" ...>
    <parameter name="date" class="java.util.Date" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[new Date()]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="50">
            <textField pattern="EEEEE dd MMMMM yyyy">
                <reportElement x="200" y="11" width="228" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{date}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Java code:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("date", new Date());
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.FRENCH);

JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, outputFile);
```

The result be:

[image: The generated report in Adobe Reader]

Comment: I tested the two way but the same result, always : **Fri Sep 28 11:29:37**

Comment: now it works, thank you very much, the problem was : instead of having : `<parameter name="datenow" class="java.util.Date"/>` I had : `<parameter name="datenow" class="java.lang.String"/>`

Comment: @Alex K ,It works with a date but not with the number. can you help me? For example, my data source is csv and I have value 85.6 in CSV now I want to use it as the german way 85,6 but whenever I apply this config then it doesn't work. (it gives 8560.0). I tried `ds.setNumberFormat` and `ds.setLocale(Locale.German)` as well. (when I remove ds.setLocal and REPORT_LOCALE parameter it shows 85.6)