# JRXlsExporter ignores Locale settings

Tags: java, date, jasper-reports

I am trying to export report to xls via *JasperReports API*. Database shows date in Russian, and I need it in Russian.
But in exported xls file the Date is in English.
I tried to insert Locale into report parameters map,

```
Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
            parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);
```

but it seems that the problem is with export, not with generation

What am I doing wrong?

Sample jrxmpl template is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport ...>
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.keep.full.text" value="true"/>
        <field name="Time" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band height="168" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH.mm.ss">
                    <reportElement x="400" y="90" width="160" height="24" uuid="22c78122-f74b-482a-9642-088d474a9f62"/>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="480" y="114" width="80" height="54" uuid="58989dd8-a634-49bc-93cc-3102a94f600a"/>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Time]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </title>
        <detail>
            <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
                <textField isBlankWhenNull="false">
                    <reportElement x="480" y="0" width="80" height="20" uuid="db69c959-5302-4d06-ba5c-413cd2aa78ed"/>
                    <box>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="8"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{Time}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

Sample java code is:

```
        Connection con = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String resource = null;
        ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT (TIME, 'dd MONTH yyyy HH24:mm') TIME FROM base");
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
            InputStream is = new FileInputStream(pathToReportsTemplates + "/"
                    + reportName + ReportConstants.TEMPLATE_FILE_EXTENSION);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(is);
            Map parameters = new HashMap();
            Locale locale = new Locale("ru", "RU");
            parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, locale);
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,
                    parameters, new JRResultSetDataSource(rs));

            JRXlsExporter exporter = new JRXlsExporter();
            exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            SimpleXlsReportConfiguration configuration = new                       SimpleXlsReportConfiguration();
            configuration.setOnePagePerSheet(false);
            exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
            File myPath = new File(outputPath);
            String fullPathToOutputFile = outputPath + "/" + reportName + "-"
                    + newTimestamp + ".xls";
            exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(
                    fullPathToOutputFile));
            exporter.exportReport();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change date format (month name) in iReport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653424/how-to-change-date-format-month-name-in-ireport)

Comment: @AlexK No, this is not a duplicate. As I said, everything is ok in Jasper, the problem is with resulting xls file. So some tuning of XLExporter needed, and I don't know how to do that. Please reconsider your editing, no answer on the ref you gave.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iReport: How to format date based on French locale](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636568/ireport-how-to-format-date-based-on-french-locale)

Comment: Thanks, but still doesn't work for JRXlsExporter...

Comment: Can you post the sample to reproduce (small jrxml + *Java* code)?

Comment: @AlexK   I added to my question, hope it is understandable )

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/5865 Seems a bug of Jasper Report.